# Solve the following inequality and graph the solution on a number line

Tags: inequality, quadratics

The question reads "Solve the following inequality and graph the solution on a number line,
${x}^{2} < -6x + 12$ "

First, when doing this, I put it all on one side to try and factor it out, but I don't believe I could've factored it out properly, so I went to use the quadratic formula and got an indeterminate answer. So, now I'm stuck on how to go along with this question to answer it...

Answer (score 1):

You're right that you should start by writing all the terms on one side. Doing this we get
$$
x^2 + 6x - 12 < 0.
$$
The function $f(x) = x^2 + 6x - 12$ is a parabola when you graph it, so what we are looking for is if the parabola ever dips below the $x$-axis. All values of $x$ where the parabola is below the axis is part of the solution.

We can find the zeros of $f$ with the quadratic formula like you suggested:
$$
x = \frac{-6 \pm \sqrt{84}}{2} = -3 \pm \sqrt{21},
$$
so the parabola crosses the $x$-axis at those values of $x$.

Now remember we want the values of $x$ where $x^2 + 6x - 12 < 0$. Here it's useful to know what a parabola looks like. Since the first term is a positive $x^2$, the parabola will open upwards, the solution set we're looking for is exactly the interval between the two zeros we solved for. So our solution is
$$
-3 - \sqrt{21} < x < -3 + \sqrt{21}.
$$
If you plot the function on Desmos or a graphing calculator it may be easier to see.